# Meta tags doesn't function

Tags: seo, meta-tags, google-search

I created a simple website for one of my clients. I added meta tags in order to end up high in Google searches. However, if I enter the name of the site or some meta keywords, Google doesn't find my website.

The critical keywords that I want to be found: "Orquidea", "schoonheidssalon Westerlo", "Westerlo", "schoonheidssalon"

I uploaded the meta tags a week ago. I think that would be long enough to be scannend and recognized by Google right?

Anyone a solution?
Here's the URL: http://www.orquidea.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question is off-topic, I'll still answer it!

FACT: Meta keywords have no effect on SEO. Instead, you should focus on generating quality content and getting [backlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink) to appropriate webpages.

Make sure to use those meta keywords only, that match the content of your client's website. And yes, don't worry about anything else.

Comment: What do you mean with "getting backlinks"?

Comment: @JorenWillems Edited the answer appropriately!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Nowadays meta tags have no effect on search engine rankings. That is Meta Tags are not considered in ranking your website. But before it was into consideration when people used to keyword stuff their meta tags.

This caused difficulty in validating websites for Google, so they used to follow only meta descriptions, content, titles. So always be careful when writing meta descriptions, titles and content. Don't stuff your content with your target keywords. Write simple content that is readable and understandable for your website and sure your website will be indexed in right place for the right keyword...

thanks